# "Employer views" is misleading, should show how many unique employers viewed the CV

Tags: feature-request, jobs

It seems that the "Employer Views of Your CV" figure does not eliminate duplicate views by the same employer, so it's not clear how many employers you've actually reached.

For example, my stats were showing 6 search hits and no views.  It then went to 7 search hits and 2 views.  Which suggests that the same employer viewed twice, otherwise how did the other one find my CV without searching?  When I declined their invitation it soon changed to 7 hits and 3 views (I'm guessing this is the same employer looking at my CV to remind themselves who I was?).  The same thing happened again yesterday.  The number of hits increased by one and the views increased by two.

So, my suggestion is to display the number of unique employer views rather than (or as well as) the total number of views.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a situation where you may want to install a tracking bug yourself.  The service I use is http://www.trackmycv.com and I've installed two tracking bugs.

One goes very near the top of [my CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/adamdavis)'s Personal Statement, and one goes near the bottom of the personal statement.

A shortened version of the personal statement is shown on search results, and the full version is shown if they view my CV.  So an employer search hit will result in a count in the shortened personal summary image, while an employer view will hit both the short and full images.

You can then find out if it's likely the same employer searches based on the results.  Unfortunately the service I note above doesn't give a great deal of statistics or information (even a raw log of IPs would be nice...) but there are many image based tracking services that can be used in a similar manner.

Comment: I would remove the one at the top of your personal statement if I were you. It's not actually shown in the search results, and in its place is something pretty ugly (something to the effect of "<link not shown>")

Comment: huh, that's disappointing...